# Close popup in review doesn't show after switching to Duplicate tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, vote-to-close

While reviewing questions in the *Close Votes* review queue, I notice regularly - but not always - that clicking on the *Close* button does not bring up the *Why should this question be closed?* popup dialog.

This happens when reviewing a duplicate question, and showing the *Duplicate* 'tab'. Clicking on the *Close* button only highlights the border of the button for a minute or so, but does nothing else. Switching back to the *Question* and clicking on *Close* does show the popup.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Review a duplicate question
2. Click on the *Duplicate* button (tab)
3. Click on the *Close* button

   => Popup dialog does not show up
4. Click on the *Question* button (tab)
5. Click on the *Close* button

   => Popup dialog shows up
6. Repeating steps 2-5 will repeatedly reproduce this.

There is no error in my browser console. I'm using Firefox 79.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [Bug in the close vote review for duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352961/289905) on MSE.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Thanks for the edit: yes, I meant Firefox, but I work a lot on and with Firebird (the database system), so my fingers went on auto-pilot and typed Firebird instead... (a manual auto-complete if you will).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in a manner of speaking, as you can no longer click the close button when looking at a duplicate.  More at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361581/235711.

Comment: Personally, I don't like the UX of this solution, because my workflow is look at the question, look at the duplicate and either agree and vote to close, or do something else. Now I still need to go back to the question and only then can I close.

Answer (score 2):

We'll take a look at this as part of the [review queue visual overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues) currently in progress and make sure things are working as intended. Thanks for the report!

We'll post an update here once that's done.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please consider also posting this answer on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352961/in-the-close-vote-review-queue-when-you-switch-to-look-at-a-duplicate-question

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Done. Thanks for the link!

Comment: In some ways it's fixed by the visual overhaul, but primarily because the option to vote to close when looking at the duplicate is entirely absent.